# I want to give in the list with input a unique number

Tags: reactjs

I want to return a list of before 2 arrays and every member of the list will have input, and each input I want to give a unique index to know how to identify it.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
```

I think it's because I do `useState` within the return, but I do not know how to give an index to each input.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'auto',
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
  listSection: {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
  },
  ul: {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
    padding: 0,
  },
}));

export default function PinnedSubheaderList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [indexInput, setIndexInput] = React.useState(0);
  const elementArr = [[0], [2,1], [0],[1],[2]]
  return (
    <List className={classes.root} subheader={<li />}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((sectionId, index) => (
        <li key={`section-${sectionId}`} className={classes.listSection}>
          <ul className={classes.ul}>
            <ListSubheader>{`I'm sticky ${sectionId}`}</ListSubheader>
            {elementArr[index].map((item) => {
            setIndexInput((prevState) => (prevState + 1))
            return (
              <ListItem key={`item-${sectionId}-${item}`}>
                <ListItemText primary={`Item ${item}`} />
                                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                  <TextField
                                    id={`input-${indexInput}`}
                                    name={`${item}`}
                                    type={`input-${indexInput}`}
                                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, indexInput)}
                                    inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                                    style={{ width: 25 }}
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItem>
)
            })}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why would you use state for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are updating your state in each and every iteration of the `map` loop.

```
setIndexInput((prevState) => (prevState + 1))
```

This results in a re-render in each and every iteration because the state is updated.

Actually, you don't need to use states here. Since you just need to use an index, you can simply use a `var` instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'auto',
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
  listSection: {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
  },
  ul: {
    backgroundColor: 'inherit',
    padding: 0,
  },
}));

export default function PinnedSubheaderList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const elementArr = [[0], [2,1], [0],[1],[2]]

  var indexInput = 0;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }

  return (
    <List className={classes.root} subheader={<li />}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((sectionId, index) => (
        <li key={`section-${sectionId}`} className={classes.listSection}>
          <ul className={classes.ul}>
            <ListSubheader>{`I'm sticky ${sectionId}`}</ListSubheader>
            {elementArr[index].map((item) => {
            indexInput++;
            return (
              <ListItem key={`item-${sectionId}-${item}`}>
                <ListItemText primary={`Item ${item}`} />
                                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                  <TextField
                                    id={`input-${indexInput}`}
                                    name={`${item}`}
                                    type={`input-${indexInput}`}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': 'labelId' }}
                                    style={{ width: 25 }}
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItem>
)
            })}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I ran the code you wrote down, I have a problem, that every time the indexInput is equal to 6, which is the number of times I do the map, it takes me the last value of the indexInput. What can be done about it?

Comment: I didn't get your problem exactly. What did you mean by "it takes me the last value of the indexInput" ?

Comment: When I click on any input, I see that its index is constantly equal to 6, every time I probably write something it activates the same index, and that way I can not separate the different inputs I have

Comment: I checked it and edited my answer. You can access the `id` easily with the `e` (event). That's more reliable and accurate than passing the `indexInput` as an arg. Please check the code now. If it solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and mark it as the correct answer :)